Rubymine pop up warning Too many results
I am getting the following error when i am searching for anything on Find in Files window on rubymine lately
Occurrences in files of total size 76 megabytes found. RubyMine may become unresponsive or even fail with OutOfMemoryError if you continue. Continue?
# VM options
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=2048m
-Xms4086m
-Xmx16096m
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=250

my laptop has 64 GB RAM
i have increased the Maximum number of results to show in the settings but i still get the same pop up.
There are multiple issues in the jetbrains bug tracker for this problem but without any real solution
is there a way to increase that limit?
